# Confused about Theorem about Tower of Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I’m confused by the notation in a lemma from my textbook:

Lemma: Let $F \subset B \subset E$ be a tower of fields with $B/F$ the splitting field of some polynomial $f \in F[x]$. If $σ \in Gal(E/F)$, then $σ|B \in Gal(B/F)$.

What does $σ|B$ even mean? I’ve never seen this notation before. Thanks!

Comment: The restriction of $\sigma$ to $B$.

Comment: @Deif Got it. Thanks!

Comment: Deif has explained the notation. This lemma says that the map $B\ni x\mapsto \sigma(x)$ is an automorphism of $B$ that fixes elements in $F$. The only non-trivial part is to make sure it is $B\to B$ and surjective, i.e. $\sigma(x)\in B$ for each $x\in B$ and every $y\in B$ is some $\sigma(x)$, $x\in B$.

Comment: Also commonly written as $\sigma |_B$